# What about other Q&A subjects

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What StackExchange sites do you want to see?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4033/what-stackexchange-sites-do-you-want-to-see)

I've heard a bit of a clamor for an automotive version.

It occurred to me that a site for kids to get help with homework, regardless of subject, ***might*** be workable. Of course, it would probably have to be heavily moderated.

Gardening? DIY?

What about it? Any other ideas?

Comment: Doesn't this kind of thing belong on Area51 (http://area51.stackexchange.com/)? I think there already are ideas over there for just about every one of the things answered below... Some of them may already be beta sites...

Comment: @jrista: Yes, but this is a really old question, so we should just close as a dupe. (It should probably be merged with the other question after it's closed.)

Comment: @Jon: Ah, sounds good. I didn't check the date when I wrote my previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

I'm an electrical engineer so I vote for one on electronics design/debugging/etc. Obvious title would be Short Circuit. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In the [Stack Overflow podcast #58](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/), Joel touched on how [Fog Creek](http://fogcreek.com/) is developing hosted, custom-topic sites using the Stack Overflow engine.

These "hosted" versions could cover any topic that a company would want.

Answer (score 2):

Robotics - [RoboOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/robooverflow)

Comment: +1 for robotics, not so much for RoboOverflow - sounds too much like some plumbing device or too much like RoboOverthrow <shudder>.

Comment: Heh. Don't get too caught up on the actual name. It's the concept that counts ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jarrod's comment, in the event that you *really* want a car forum (which is the example I'll use cause I think it's awesome) for this sort of thing, I would bite the bullet, pay the $X/month for a 3 month trial run with FogCreek, and then try and reach critical mass with some car websites to promote it.

I would hope Joel would be reasonable about "Open Hobbyist" groups of this sort, and let you run ads to pay him his money.

And now, you've got a semi-viable business that can operate in either a not-for-profit or for-profit model and have an open, non-corporate-driven car enthusiast board.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics - MathOverflow

Stack Overflow is the best Q&A system I have ever seen on the Internet. I am getting a lot of help on stackoverflow.com, it only lacks many other subjects.

Comment: But not mathoverflow.net? You probably mean a MathOverflow that is not as restrictive?