# Is the name of a Stack Exchange 2.0 site fixed after the definition phase?

Tags: support, area-51, site-proposal

Is it possible to change the name of a Stack Exchange 2.0 site after the definition phase?

For example, could "[Electronics and Robotics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651?phase=definition)" be changed to "Short Circuit and Robo Overflow"? This is just an example. (Origin of names: [Short Circuit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-about-other-qa-subjects/238#238), [Robo Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/what-about-other-qa-subjects/2589#2589)).

Comment: I *love* Short Circuit. And it won't work as a domain name (Needs to be a .com) but `shortcircu.it` is still available :)

Comment: ... I just realized I fixed a typo in a Peter Mortensen post. I didn't even know that was possible ... do I get a badge for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The domain, and hence site, name is one of the things that's chosen during the beta phase.

See the [Site Attributes](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/site-attributes) question on the Web Applications meta.

However, it is not fixed and can be changed if there is a compelling reason to do so. <strike>Not Programming Related</strike> <strike>Programmers</strike> Software Engineering has been through two name changes.

Comment: Agree with that the site name can be changed as it have done in the past. Regarding the link, if I understand correctly the post in Web Applications Meta was the first post having the elements to be choosen on the early days of specific beta. That lead to a blog article, that was used as reference on multiple beta ran in 2010 and many later. In 2014 it was posted a new version that has [tag:faq]  : [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/289691) (it doesn't include the domain / site name).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, various site name and domain name changes happened long after sites left the private beta phase, sometimes even as part of their graduation from beta. Here's an example from <s>Programming Puzzles & Code Golf</s> Code Golf & Coding Challenges: [Here's your site design preview!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/heres-your-site-design-preview)

A complete list of name changes is maintained as a Community Wiki [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286109/295232).