# Was Programmers (now Software Engineering) the first SE site to change its name?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-history, site-name

[*Programmers Stack Exchange* is now officially *Software Engineering Stack Exchange*](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8266/44315), which made me curious about history:  is this the first time this has happened?

Has any SE site previously changed its name after launch?  Is SE.SE a first?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not the first. Here are the other renames across the network:

- [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com) née [Food and Cooking](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904)
- [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com) née IT Security
- [Community Building](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com) née Moderators.
- [Music: Practice & Theory](http://music.stackexchange.com) née Musical Practice & Performance
- [Arqade](http://arqade.com) née Gaming
- [Beer, Wine & Spirits](http://alcohol.stackexchange.com) née Beer
- [Mi Yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com) née Jewish Life & Learning
- [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) née History of Science and Math
- [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) née WordPress Answers
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) née ["a whole lot of different names"](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5226/51760)
- [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) née [Writers](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/14426)
- [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) née [Cognitive Sciences](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2294/14337)
- [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) née [Health](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/956)
- [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) née [Photography and Photographic Editing](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/605)
- [Bricks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com) née [Lego Answers](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389)
- [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) née [Materials Modeling](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/96/118)
- [Substrate & Polkadot](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/) née [Substrate](https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17/2)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) née Nothing to Install née Web Apps. See [Public Service Announcement: ongoing, offsite discussion about Area 51 graduates' branding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66443/)

Comment: Don't forget the original Programmers rename (NPR). :)

Comment: @hichris123 I was thinking about that earlier today... and for the life of me I can't recall if it launched into private beta as Not Programming Related or if it was "renamed" before private beta launch. :) My memory apparently doesn't go *quite* that far back.

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3415/124654) it was launched as Programmers. So, your memory isn't all that bad. :)

Comment: @hichris123 Looks like it was graduated as Programmers, but was in beta as Not Programming Related. Seems about right. As I recall, it was the last site in the network that graduated after 90 days in public beta, which was the expected schedule at the time.

Comment: Mi Yodeya was an SE 1.0 site that become Jewish Life & Learning, an SE 2.0 beta site, that then became Mi Yodeya when it graduated.  No URL change at graduation, though, which is consistent with (e.g.) Ask Different which is apple.SE, Seasoned Advice which is cooking.SE, and probably others.

Comment: I've edited to just make a list... please feel free to edit to add any other ones.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to simply list all these sites renames in [Recent feature changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/165773) log. Frankly it was the first thing I tried to check when I saw this question because I expected them listed over there. Was quite disappointed to find out that site renames aren't tracked there

Comment: Pretty sure that Mechanics was once called Garage https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1814/more-creative-name-for-mechanics-se, but I'm not sure when it was changed.

Answer (score 5):

No it's not the first. [Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/) used to be called Musical Practice and Performance and it was changed on the [site's road to graduation](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/989/music-se-is-getting-a-new-name-music-practice-theory).