# Is "Software Engineering" the replacement of "Programmers"?

Tags: support, software-engineering-se, site-name

I can't find the "Programmers" site anywhere and haven't seen the "Software Engineering" site before - is it the replacement of "Programmers"?

Comment: Yes, according to the following topic on the site's Meta, [Programmers is now Software Engineering Stack Exchange](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8266/its-official-programmers-is-now-software-engineering-stack-exchange).

Comment: FWIW your recent closed and deleted question over there ([Where to start learning design patterns?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/336083/31260 "10K link")) has been off-topic for last several years, long before site rename. And [since July 2013](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/5992/31260) there is even a predefined close reasons for such questions: "career or education advice"...

Comment: ...from perspective of folks asking such questions, the only difference somewhat related to (or more precisely conincident with) site rename is that moderators were instructed to [close and delete such questions immediately](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=31225279#31225279) instead of waiting for community to take care of that

Answer (score 30):

It is the **renamed** and re-scoped Programmers, yes.

This [happened](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8266/its-official-programmers-is-now-software-engineering-stack-exchange) after a lot of discussion about this within the site meta.

Given it has a new scope, if one is to ask a question there, I suggest reading their [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see what's on topic *before* posting.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286109/152859) for a full list of past renames across Stack Exchange.

Comment: I am not sure that "new scope" is the accurate wording. I for one [wanted scope to stay the same](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8062/31260) from the very start of this change and I followed all the process along to make sure it stays and as far as I can tell it really stays. It's rather that _description_ of the scope was polished and is now enforced more strictly, including [immediate mod deletion of blatantly off-topic questions](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8145/31260)

Comment: @gnat - fair enough. My comment was more for people who were not aware of the name/domain change and what's behind it (essentially - asking people to always read the site "on topic" docs before posting).

Comment: ...(sigh) you know Oded it looks like [some people just won't learn no matter what](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/336157/31260 "posting again a blatantly off-topic question despite all the advice given, oh my")