# Help people find the lost Programmers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, software-engineering-se, site-name, site-description

People [keep](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286962/is-software-engineering-the-replacement-of-programmers?noredirect=1) [losing](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287269/where-is-the-programmers-site?noredirect=1) the Programmers site. This is expected, a big site suddenly going through an overall name change.

Instead of having them ask here on Meta, or give up and believe it's deleted, I suggest to help them find it again.

How? By adding "Formerly known as Programmers" to the site description. This way, if one will search for the word "programmers" in the [sites list on stackexchange.com](//stackexchange.com/sites), or in the sites list inside the top bar Drop Down, they will easily find it.

Currently, if one search for "programmers" in the sites list, they are getting two results:

> [image]

...and...

> [image]

Those are not what the person had in mind. With my suggestion implemented, it would look like this:

> [image]

Comment: I'm betting that many of the Software Engineering people might regard not coming up in a search for "programmers" as a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Brad why not? The name has changed, they already won. Can't see how helping existing users who weren't around for a while, or people who heard the old site name in the past, find the site, is so awful.

Comment: Wasn't the whole point of changing the name to discourage these folks from asking their off-topic questions there?  Really, the site has little to do with programmers, which is why we made the name change in the first place.  This isn't just a nit; in defense of the name change, SE specifically called out the fact that "programmers" is a *group of people,* not a topic area.

Comment: @RobertHarvey all true. But just adding "formerly known as..." should not imply it is still for programmers.

Comment: I like this idea. “Programmers” as a brand will not die over night, and we should accommodate people searching for that brand. We should not help people searching for a place to dump any kind of programming-related question, but I doubt this addition would accomplish that. However, the addition should be put at the *end* of the description where it's less noticeable.

Comment: There is no more "Programmers."  Let the brand die peacefully.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is exactly why we spent eight months refining the documented scope before changing the name: folks generally thought Programmers was a different site from the one it had become.

The change to the name, description, tour, etc. all combine to emphasize that this is NOT the site you thought you knew.

We want folks to approach Software Engineering with fresh eyes, not clouded by the long and tumultuous history of Programmers. So, no, no shortcuts.

Comment: Pretty much what few comments on the question said, but that miss my point, in a way. I'm not talking only about new users, but mainly about people who already used the site in the past, weren't active in its meta, and one day the site is "gone".

Comment: Yeah, but... You linked to an example of a person looking for Programmers to ask a question that very much did not belong there. That's the sort of misconception I'm talking about breaking here.

Comment: You mean [this user](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/57952/alex)? Four years member, and the [question](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336700/request-data-from-wikidata-every-time-or-save-it-in-database) got upvote, plus upvoted answer. Can't see anything bad in all of that. I just think there are more like him, who won't bother to ask and look where the site went to, and just go away, True, they likely won't make awesome users, but still, they're not bad either.

Comment: @ShadowWizard FWIW one needn't use meta to learn about what's going on. Site moderators diligently tagged [new-site-name](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-site-name) discussions "featured" meaning these were prominently displayed at site sidebar for over half year while this thing was in progress. One had to abstain of visiting _main site_ for these months to miss that. Think of [Rip Van Winkle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_Van_Winkle)

Comment: @gnat people don't read side bars. That's true for new users, and veteran users.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286962/is-software-engineering-the-replacement-of-programmers @sha (I'm on mobile at the DMV, didn't follow your other link).

Comment: @ShadowWizard 7K views on [main discussion](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7935/31260) suggest that people generally tend to pay attention

Comment: @Shog9 that user doesn't even have account there, so how you know he is going to "ask a question that very much did not belong there"? He's example for someone who heard somehow the term "Programmers Stack Exchange" and went looking for it.

Comment: @gnat out of [112330 users with more than 1 rep](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/582764/users-with-more-than-1-rep) - not that much, it also counts anonymous visitors in there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard note these 7K count much less than those who just noticed (and thus learned about the change) - these are only those who noticed _and_ decided to visit meta to find more. And that is only on one question of about a dozen discussions, and that is only on a question that hanged featured for only ~3 months of 8

Comment: He does, @Sha - it's just hidden. Anyway, stop thinking about this as a "Arqade"-style rebranding; that was never the point. You're familiar, I'm sure, with the problems Programmers struggled with over the years - this is closer to an attempt to reboot the site without the insane amount of work normally associated with such things, to build on the engaged userbase while leaving as much of the last 6 years of baggage behind as is possible. Seasoned regulars can say "nothing really changed" if they want, but I ain't saying or even implying that to anyone else.

Comment: @Shog9 OK, guess I'm out of ammo here. While I still would prefer to make it easier to remember the past, as bad as it may be, I accept the rejection. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

The domain http://programmers.stackexchange.com still does, and probably always will, redirect to wherever Programmers.SE has gone. People who visit old links to posts will still find those posts.

Comment: True, but not everyone keep bookmarks or goes directly to domains.